# What determines the format of / information in HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID?

Tags: asp.net

What determines the format of / information in HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID?

It is usually in the format /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Blah

So what is LM? 1? etc.

Please don't just post links unless they explicitly state what the different parts are.

Cheers,

-- Lee

Comment: Seems to be the MetaBase path for IIS. I know you asked not to have links, but here is one anyway ;-). It explains the metabase structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524661(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Cheers David, Instead of a comment why don't you reply with the same as an answer and i'll consider marking it as the correct answer as it looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the MetaBase path for IIS. I know you asked not to have links, but here is one anyway ;-). It explains the [metabase structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524661%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). For instance, the article explains that LM means "Local Machine".